# Supressing rowsPerPage (pagination) in Grid of Tapestry

Tags: java, tapestry

**Is there any way in Tapestry 5 to suppress pagination for a gird
component?**

I searched all over the internet, couldn't find a solution. I have a requirement to display a grid with the full list
regardless of it's length. My observations:

- I tried `t:rowsPerPage=0` but got a divide by
  zero error.
- Tried -1 as well, didn't work.
- If I remove `rowsPerPage` entirely, I see 25 rows. (Looks like this must be the default value.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from the [javadoc](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.html) that the default is `symbol:tapestry.components.grid_rows_per_page` so you could override this symbol if you'd like to do it globally. Another option is:

TML

```
<t:grid source="..." rowsPerPage="prop:rowsPerPage" />
```

Java

```
public int getRowsPerPage() {
   return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set rowsperpage to a very large number